# What are the practical (if any) problems with PA and the existence of non-standard models

Tags: logic, soft-question, peano-axioms

Forgive me if this question sounds naive or somewhat poorly constructed due to my nebulous understanding of the concepts involved...

I have recently been reading about the nature of PA, and how, being a first-order theory, it leads to the existence of multiple non-standard models.  On the other hand, while second-order logic provides a single model of the natural numbers, it has problems in that the proof system is not complete.  So it seems that a first-order theory is the best we have.

So my question is, how does the existence of non-standard models, which I believe entails the existence of numbers 'beyond' the natural numbers, affect the working mathematician in real life, if at all?  Does it materially affect any field of mathematics outside of mathematical logic?  Can we just ignore the existence of such rogue elements, or can they in some way 'interfere' with the properties and workings of the natural numbers and other number systems derived from them?

Again, if any of my assertions or assumptions are false, please let me know.

Comment: It usually doesn't affect normal mathematicians at all in their daily life. When a number theorist is working on divisibility theorems and prime numbers, he usually doesn't spare a single thought to Peano's axioms, or whether his theory of natural numbers is a first order one or a second order one, or whether there are non-standard systems out there somewhere.

Comment: "practical" ? NO. But see [Non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis#Introduction).

Comment: Usually non-logicians use set theory as the base theory, and so for instance number theorists only focus on $\mathbb{N}$, the standard model of arithmetic, so to them it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Arthur   That's good to know, that I'm worrying about nothing.  I just had some concerns that there may be some concessions that had to be made when using second-order logic over first order logic.  That is, that some things maybe provable from one but not from the other...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it's certainly interesting that non-standard models can be useful...

Comment: To be clear, of course number theorists use induction on a daily basis, and they know that the action of adding $1$ is injecitive on the natural numbers and hits every natural number except $0$, and so on. They just don't think of that collection of statements as what defines $\Bbb N$

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would the existence of nonstandard models "affect" anybody?

Comment: The ideas around nonstandard models don't entail their existence, they simply demonstrate that their existence can't be ruled out.

Comment: @DanielV: ZF proves the existence of non-standard models of PA.

Comment: @RobArthan I guess I said that ambiguously.  Proving the existence of a model for a logic L isn't the same as proving that the existence of those objects in L.  It is very skolem paradoxy.  The statement "entails the existence of numbers 'beyond' the natural numbers" is very misleading.